# How can you restrict FineUploader from accepting drag-and-drop directories?

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

What is the best way to **allow** drag-and-drop [FineUploader](http://fineuploader.com/) functionality but **disallow** directories?  The use case here is forcing a user to upload one or more files instead of a directory (which may have dozens of sub-directories).

The solution should provide a friendly notification message (e.g. JavaScript alert) combined with denying the directory upload.

Answer (score 1):

Folder dropping is only supported in Chrome and recent versions of Opera. It will likely never be supported in other browsers, as [the web specification that enables this behavior](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/) is dead. That said, there is nothing *you* can do to prevent Fine Uploader from accepting dropped directories in any browser, short of disabling drag and drop behavior. I also have no plans to implement this sort of control, as it seems unlikely to have wide appeal.

If Fine Uploader *were* to add an option that would allow folders to be ignored when handling dropped files, it could only be enforced in Chrome/Opera, since other browsers don't even have a concept of "folders" in the context of dropped objects. When a user drops something into a drop zone, Fine Uploader is provided a `DataTransfer` object on the drop `Event`. This `DataTransfer` object, in Chrome/Opera, contains a pseduo-array of `Entry` objects. `Entry` is a top-level interface with other lower-level interfaces that include `FileEntry` and `DirectoryEntry`. Fine Uploader could simply ignore `DirectoryEntry` items in this case. Though this is a simplistic approach and likely would not be appropriate for all cases.